# Combining angularJS and d3.js: Refreshing a plot after submitting new input parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

I would like that after I click on the `submit` button with new values inside input fields, my network `d3.js` plot would get updated based on the new graph generated by **new** input values. Here in the following, you can find my example code:

**GenerateGraph.js** This file contains a bunch of functions which generate a `graph` (**randomGraph**) based on the *submitted* input values. Then the graph is needed to get refreshed in the browser.

```
function degree(node,list){
  var deg=new Array();
  for (var i=0; i<node.length; i++){
    var count=0;
    for (var j=0; j<list.length; j++){
        if (node[i]==list[j][0] || node[i]==list[j][1]){
          count++;
        }
    }
    deg.push(count);
  }
  return deg;
}
function randomGraph (n, m) { //creates a random graph on n nodes and m links
  var graph={};
  var nodes = d3.range(n).map(Object),
      list  = randomChoose(unorderedPairs(d3.range(n)), m),
      links = list.map(function (a) { return {source: a[0], target: a[1]} });
  graph={
  Node:nodes,
  ListEdges:list,
  Links:links
  }
  return graph;
}

function randomChoose (s, k) { // returns a random k element subset of s
  var a = [], i = -1, j;
  while (++i < k) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length);
    a.push(s.splice(j, 1)[0]);
  };
  return a;
}

function unorderedPairs (s) { // returns the list of all unordered pairs from s
  var i = -1, a = [], j;
  while (++i < s.length) {
    j = i;
    while (++j < s.length) a.push([s[i],s[j]])
  };
  return a;
}
```

**network.html**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">     
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
     <title>graph</title>

     <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>     
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
     <script src="GenerateGraph.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="svgGraph.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <h1 class="title">Simulating a network</h1>
     <div id="outer" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="col-md-6">
        <network-inputs inputs="networkInputs" submit="submit(inputs)"></network-inputs>
     </div> 
    <!--test -->
     <script type="text/javascript">

        //get the input parameters for plotting
         angular.module("myApp", [])

         .directive('networkInputs', function() {

         return {
                restrict: 'E',                
                scope: {
                   inputs: '<',
                   submit: '&'
                },
                link : link,               
                template: 
              '<h3 >Initialise new parameters to generate a network </h3>'+
                    '<form ng-submit="submit({inputs: inputs})" class="form-inline">'+
                      '<div class="form-group">'+
                         '<label>Number of nodes</label>'+
                         '<input type="number" min="10" class="form-control" ng-model="inputs.N" ng-required="true">'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<div class="form-group">'+
                         '<label>Number of links</label>'+
                          '<input type="number" min="0.1" class="form-control" ng-model="inputs.m" ng-required="true">'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<button style="color:black; margin: 1rem 4rem;" type="submit">Generate</button>' +
                   '</form>'};
         })
         .factory("initialiseNetwork",function(){
            var data = {
                            N: 20,
                            m: 50,

                       };

            return {
                networkInputs:data
            };      

         })

         .controller("MainCtrl",  ['$scope','initialiseNetwork' ,function($scope,initialiseNetwork) {

               $scope.networkInputs={};
               $scope.mySVG=function(){
                         var graph=randomGraph($scope.networkInputs.N, $scope.networkInputs.m);

                };

               function init(){
                  $scope.networkInputs=initialiseNetwork.networkInputs;
                   //Run the function which generates the graph and plot it 

               }
               init();

               $scope.submit = function(inputs) {

                   var dataObject = {
                       N: inputs.N,
                       m: inputs.m
                   };
                   //lets simply log them but you can plot or smth other 
                   console.log($scope.networkInputs); 

               }

         }]);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**svgGraph.js**

```
function link(scope,element, attrs){
    //SVG size
    var width = 1800,
    height = 1100;

    // We only need to specify the dimensions for this container.

    var vis = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
              .attr('width', width)
              .attr('height', height);
    var force = d3.layout.force()
                      .gravity(.05)
                      .distance(100)
                      .charge(-100)
                      .size([width, height]);
        // Extract the nodes and links from the data.
     scope.$watch('val',function(newVal,oldVal){
                   vis.selectAll('*').remove();
                   if (!newVal){
                       return;
                   }

        var Glinks = newVal.links;
        var W=degree(newVal.nodes,newVal.list);

        var Gnodes = [];
        var obj=newVal.nodes;
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
           Gnodes.push({"name":key, "count":W[key]});
        });

        //Creates the graph data structure 
        force.nodes(Gnodes)
             .links(Glinks)
             .linkDistance(function(d) { 
              return(0.1*Glinks.length); 
             })//link length
             .start();
         //Create all the line svgs but without locations yet
        var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
           .data(Glinks)
           .enter().append("line")
           .attr("class", "link")
           .style("stroke-width","0.3px");

        //Do the same with the circles for the nodes - no 
        var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
            .data(Gnodes)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(force.drag);
        node.append("circle")
             .attr("r", function(d){
              return d.count*0.5;   
            })
            .style("opacity", .3)
            .style("fill", "red");
        //add degree of node as text 
        node.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) { return d.count })
            .attr("font-family",'Raleway',"Tangerine");
        //Now we are giving the SVGs co-ordinates - the force layout is generating the co-ordinates which this code is using to update the attributes of the SVG elements
        force.on("tick", function () {
             link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                 return d.source.x;
                 })
                 .attr("y1", function (d) {
                 return d.source.y;
                 })
                 .attr("x2", function (d) {
                 return d.target.x;
                 })
                 .attr("y2", function (d) {
                 return d.target.y;
                 });

              node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        });      
    });
}
```

The link in the **plunker** is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/TMjCll1HSOcXzqGns1ep?p=preview).

Comment: Could you please reduce your problem into a [mcve]?  It's more work to go through all that code.  Make it easy for us to help you

Comment: @ochi I assure you I simplified it but I also need that these pieces work together.

Comment: Could you put together a fiddle/plnkr demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @charlcheel I left a link to the `plnkr` in the bottom of the question. It used to plot with the initial value but wasn't getting refreshed by submit button. I made some changes now it doesn't generate the initial plot. Some connections are missing.

Comment: @charlcheel I saw some example online that if I want to initialise `svg`, it should be in `directive` but I don't know how to transfer initial input parameters of my `randomGraph` function to it and from there to my `link` function to plot the `graph`.

Comment: Per your comment a few minutes ago, what is required to just get the graph to show? It is best to start with the basics working and then people can help from there

Comment: @KScandrett I `               $scope.networkInputs={};
               $scope.mySVG=function(){
                         var graph=randomGraph($scope.networkInputs.N, $scope.networkInputs.m);
                         makeSVG(graph);
                };
               
               function init(){
                  $scope.networkInputs=initialiseNetwork.networkInputs;
                   //Run the function which generates the graph and plot it 
                   $scope.mySVG();
               }
               init();`

Comment: @KScandrett adding this to controller was giving me an initial `d3.js` plot but wasn't get updated by calling `mySVG` function which was just getting `graph` object as an input in the `submit` function later.

Comment: @KScandrett watching talks about how to combine `d3.js` and `Angular`, I must put the `d3.js` part in directive and pass it through `link` function and set `$watch` to observe the change in **graph** value, in order to update the plot.

Comment: @KScandrett I deleted in the version I posted here. I was trying out `directive` approach.

Comment: @KScandrett I am trying to put pieces together but hasn't worked so far.

Comment: Focus on the basics - just get your page showing a graph so that people can help from there with the refresh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - In the directive, you watch val, which in controller is $scope.data, so I guess you need it for every submitted form? then just assign the data to $scope.data every submit:

```
$scope.submit = function(inputs) {
    var dataObject = {
      N: inputs.N,
      m: inputs.m
    };
    $scope.data = randomGraph(dataObject.N, dataObject.m);
}
```

2 - Then, in sgvGraph.js, in the scope.watch, you use var newVal.nodes and newVal.list anf newVal.link which are all undefined because you build your object with {Node:.., Links:..., ListEdges:...}

3 - Should add novalidate in form and manage the error manually, because I cant submit with the min="0.1" with chrome

This is the working plunkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/PbynuNCPM4Jv4lPmK8eW/

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. There is only one thing that is missing. How can I generate a plot in the browser with initial values? Before when I had separate function  for plotting that wasn't in directive I was calling it in the controller `init()` function and the page was rendering with initial values.

Comment: For now, to have the generated graph, you just need to change $scope.data to the data created by randomGraph(), so adding $scope.data = randomGraph($scope.networkInputs.N, $scope.networkInputs.m); in the init() function will work, I updated the plnkr